# Passing code through the post variable?

Tags: php, file

I am coding a small template editor and the problem I am having is that code keeps getting converted into other characters, such as:

```
&lt;?php

$hello = "hello";

?&gt;
```

and it writes exactly that to the file, I want to write the actual code, php and html.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: change whatever is calling `htmlspecialchars` or similar...

Comment: what are you using as an editor? standard post will not do that.

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case you should run the contents of the file through the `html_entity_decode` function.

> Description from the [documentation](http://il.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) -
>   Convert special characters to HTML entities

```
$str = '&lt;?php';
echo html_entity_decode($str);
```

Outputs - `<?php`

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that your PHP is calling [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).  This converts characters that could be an issue (such as `<>`) into their HTML-safe version.  You can resolve this by removing the `htmlspecialchars()` function (not recommended, as it's probably there for a reason) or calling [`html_entity_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) on the code you want to save to a file.

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't necessarily recommend using html_entity_decode. It's usually a bad idea to fix incorrectly-encoded text by just reversing the encoding. Instead, figure out why it's encoded incorrectly in the first place.